# Jquery IE only error !

Tags: jquery, browser, jquery-selectors

I have this script to **copy multiple value** of **textbox1** [which are **separated by ENTER**] to **textbox2.**

It works perfect in all browser except **IE**.

In **IE** all **multiple values** [which are **separated by ENTER**] are **copied** in **single line** **[without ENTER]** like a **single value**, Which in turn affecting my form submission.

my code is something like this.

```
<html>
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>  
<body>  

<p>Textarea1</p>    
<textarea name="a" id="ajax" cols="60" rows="8"></textarea>

<p>Textarea2</p>    
<textarea name="b" id="client" cols="60" rows="8"></textarea>  

<br><br>      
<input type="checkbox" id="Get">
<p>Check this box to copy values</p>  


<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
if (this.checked) {
    $('#client').html($('#ajax').val());
    }
      else {
    $('#client').html($('').val());
     }
   }); 
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Can Anybody Figure it out.. Where I am going wrong ?

**Thanks.**

-manndaar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your copy/delete code to this:

```
if (this.checked) {
  $('#client').val($('#ajax').val());
} else {
  $('#client').val('');
}
```